# Is the projection of an universally measurable set again universally measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $(Y,\mathcal{B}(Y))$ be a polish space together with the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra.
There is a Theorem that states: The projection $\pi_X(B)$ of every measurable set $B \in \mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}(Y)$ on $X$ is universally measurable w.r.t. $(X,\mathcal{A})$.
But does there exist a universally measurable set (w.r.t. $(X \times Y,\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}(Y))$) whose projection on $X$ is not universally measurable w.r.t. $X$?